# Path Cache Triggers Events on All Children When Adding and Deleting One (curator-recipe 1.0.1)

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm using curator-recipe's (1.0.1, because of storm 0.7.4) path cache
to watch getChildren event on a path. When adding or deleting a child,
it triggers add/update on all children.

e.g. there's /mypath/1, /mypath/2, when adding /mypath/3, all 1, 2 and
3 are reported modified.

Editing a child is fine. Only the target child's event is triggered.

I tried PathChildrenCacheMode.CACHE_PATHS_ONLY as well as
PathChildrenCacheMode.CACHE_DATA_AND_STAT, if that matters.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

FYI - PathChildrenCache was been re-written since Curator 1.0.x so you might try again.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Curator